# Some of mp4 video not playing in html5 . How we will resolve this?

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4

```
<video width="480"controls>
     <source src="video/kahani.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="video/kahanisong.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This is my code here "kahani.mp4" is playing well but "kahanisong.mp4" is not playing.
How to resolve it ???

Comment: Is the file kahanisong.mp4 present in the video folder?

Comment: Yes "kahanisong.mp4" file is present in video folder